# Having problems to connect AMFPHP with an AS file

Tags: php, actionscript-3, port, amfphp, netconnection

Im trying to connect AMFPHP with an actionscript file, everything is working perfectly except the part of the connection between them.

This is how I try to connect the .as file with the service:

```
_netConnection = new NetConnection(); 
_netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
_netConnection.connect("http://localhost/Core/Gateway.php");
```

The thing is, I cant make it work. I also tried to replace http for rtmpt (http tunneling) but it also doesnt work, I added the port after localhost, I tried several, no luck.

Depending on the port I add after localhost, the onNetStatus is not even called, or it says that it cant connect.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) have you set your services-config.xml and compiler arguments?  2) have you browsed the gateway url, is all ok with php (any errors)?  I found this on google maybe check it ... http://groups.drupal.org/node/2768

Comment: Do You running Your SWF from local host too ? Or debug/test flashplayer window ?

Comment: @Adrian 1) no, I didnt set the services config or compiler argument 2) yes, the php is working. Turbosqel from another folder

Answer (score 1):

your url looks funny. If it's amfphp V2.x, you should be pointing at Amfphp/ (or Amfphp/index.php)

Comment: Yeah, I changed that and now works, I checked the troubleshooting section in your forum, it was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you could tell us the version of you amfphp it would be more convenient to answer. Assuming you are using Amphp v 2.x here goes a piece of concept.

in flex, write something like this:

```
var _amf:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject();
    _amf.destination = "dummyDestination";
    _amf.endpoint = "/Amfphp/";
    _amf.source = "yourphp";
    _amf.phpFunctionYouWantToCallWithParameterIfNeeded;
```

that's all you basically need to create a connection between flex and amfphp 2.x